# How can I stop the status bar from hiding?

Tags: home-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-10, nova-launcher

On my Samsung S10 with Nova as the main launcher, I'm noticing that for a few days now I don't have a status bar when on my home screen. The status bar is there when I'm working from inside any application, but as soon as I move the the home screen, it is pulled up somehow (literally, I see it moving up and disappearing). I can easily get it back by just swiping my finger from the top of the screen just a bit downwards which is why I don't think this is a bug or the launcher somehow covering it. But I'd prefer for the status bar to remain visible all the time.

I'm really not aware of anything I have done to cause this. I might have pressed something by mistake but I did not tinker with my phone in some meaningful way.

I tried googling this but all I get is results about how to show or hide notifications or icons within the status bar. When it comes to hiding and unhiding the status bar, I could only find development examples but as mentioned, I have never developed anything on this phone, it's also not rooted.

Some help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nova has a "Notification bar" setting to hide it on the Home Screen. Look for it under "Look & feel". Change its state to experiment to taste. When experimenting, generally ONE setting at a time reduces later confusion.

Comment: @wbogacz that was it. I never set this, I guess there must be some kind of shortcut to activate this which got triggered by accident. Thanks. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nova Launcher has dozens of settings for its Home Screen layout and personalization. Included is a `Notification bar` setting, which allows the device owner to hide it on the Home Screen.

It can be found under the `Look & feel` settings.

Change the state of `Show notification bar` to experiment to taste.